# CMake concatenate to each string in array

Tags: c++, cmake

For example I have array:

```
set(SOURCES
        main
        file
        app
        )

foreach(src ${SOURCES})
    set(${src} "${src}.cpp")
endforeach()

foreach(src ${SOURCES})
    message(${src})
endforeach()
```

I need to receive main.cpp, file.cpp and app.cpp, but it doesn't work.
Why? How can I solve it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command

```
set(${src} "${src}.cpp")
```

creates a variable, i.e. you create `${main}`, `${file}`, and `${app}` variables in the loop.

Instead, you need to modify the list `SOURCES`, as described in [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html).

```
list(REMOVE_ITEM SOURCES ${src})
list(APPEND SOURCES "${src}.cpp")
```

But do not modify `SOURCES` it in the loop over `SOURCES`. Instead, just create a temporary list, and then swap them.

```
foreach(src ${SOURCES})
    list(APPEND SOURCES_tmp "${src}.cpp")
endforeach()
set(SOURCES ${SOURCES_tmp})
```

If you need to modify the whole list, it better to use the command `list(TRANSFORM ...)`.